# Import an array from external file

Tags: javascript, html

I make a chart with this code:

**HTML CODE**

```
<div id="placeholder" style="width:600px;height:300px;"></div>
```

**JS CODE**

```
 var all_data = [
                 {
                  data: [
                          [a,b], 
                          [c,d]
                        ]
                  }
                ];

 // свойства графика

var plot_conf = {
 series: {
   lines: { 
     show: true,
     lineWidth: 2 
   }
 },

 };

 $.plot($("#placeholder"), all_data, plot_conf);
```

My question - how can I import values of a,b,c and d from external file (txt-file)?

Comment: Use AJAX to read the file from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Do you can put the values in JSON file and read with AJAX